# Git - merging commits in pull request, when everything before was done through github.com

Tags: git, github, pull-request

as title says, I want to merge commits in pull request, but everything before, like commits, making pull request, commiting to branch, that is in pull request, was done at website github.com.
I thought that its easier do this at website, just few clicks and no problem, but with these more complicated things its better do it through terminal.

What I have only done

`git clone https://github.com/...
cd repository_name`

So question is - what should I do now, to merge my commits in pull request? I dont have here branches, that I see at github.com, so I even dont know how to switch to branch, that is connected with that pull request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Pull Request is only a name for awaiting merge. It's not a command in git - it's a state in github that waits for

```
git merge branch_name
```

It's usually for code review purpose or testing the code before merging to master branch. So what you really want to do locally is to make a merge. First you need to get those remote branches from github. To do this use

```
git fetch -a
```

After which you'll have your branches locally. Then change for the one you want to make "pull request" from with

```
git checkout branch_to_make_pr_from
git merge branch_to_make_pr_to
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question,

But if you want to merge many commits in one you need `git rebase -i HEAD~n` where n is the number of commits you want to merge from HEAD.

You can see a good video that explain this procedure [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qh9KtjfjzCU)